# how to change black background to transparent view in opengl-es(iphone)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, opengl-es

opengles -eaglview have a particle animation with background black color.but i don't want black color.i like only transparent view because my view controller already have an image(BG).
i want to apply particle effects on the uiimageview.
how to change black background to transparent view in opengl-es(iphone)?please help me...[image]

it is actual output.. it is created in opengles view;
but i don't wants background black color...

Comment: Be aware that overlaying non-opaque OpenGL ES content will lead to significantly slowed rendering.  You'd probably be better served by taking your background image and placing it as a texture behind your sparkling effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your rendering loop for the opengl view are you clearing the alpha to 0.0?

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
```

Also, have you set the opaque and drawableProperties of the view correctly? For transparent backgrounds I use:

```
yourlayer.opaque=NO;

yourlayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEaglDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
```